# Making a multilevel list with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm Trying to make a multi-level menu for CSS, I can't achieve to collapse the submenus into the main menus.

For some reason, is showing me all the options before i even hoover it with the mouse.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("http://goadvanced.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/RicLogoNew_186CMYK-Orangey.jpeg");
    background-size: 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center; 
    }



ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}



/* hover */

ul li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }




li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

li:hover li { float: none; }

li:hover a { background: #1bc2a2; }

li:hover li a:hover { background: #2c3e50; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#Mercure">Mercure</a></li>

  <li><a href="#Impresora / Escáner">Impresora / Escáner</a></li>
  </ul>
  <li><a href="#Impresora / Escáner">Impresora / Escáner</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Impresora / Escáner">Pistolas Tracking</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Impresora / Escáner">TPA - TPV</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active"><script type="text/javascript">
    var d=new Date()
    var weekday=new Array("Domingo - Dimanche","Lunes - Lundi","Martes - Mardi","Miercoles - Mercredi","Jueves - Jeudi",
                "Viernes - Vendredi","Sabado - Samedi")
    document.write("Hoy es: " + weekday[d.getDay()])


</script></a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried with adding display:block; in the first ul, worked a bit but not the entire menu.

Comment: Don't you think, your HTML is all wrong.. your `UL` starts somewhere, but it ends twice. Your `script` tag is placed at wrong place.
It would be clear, if you could put an image of what exactly you want to achieve..!

Comment: Check this: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/create-a-multi-level-drop-down-menu-with-pure-css/